# Array for json in <select>

Tags: java, html, arrays

I want to pass an array with "json" in `<select>`.

```
<select id="artikel-select" name="artikel">
</select>

<script>
    $('kategorie-select').observe('change', function(event){
        var url = 'getartikel.php?kategorie=' + $('kategorie-select').value;
        new Ajax.Request(url,
                            {
                            method: 'get',
                            onSuccess: function(transport, json)
                            {
                            var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON(true);
                            // Selectbox reset
                            $('artikel-select').length = 0;
                            // Artikel der Selectbox hinzufuegen
                            json.each(function(artikel)
                            {
                            newoption = new Option(artikel.typ, artikel.manu, false, false);
                            $('artikel-select').options[$('artikel-select').length] = newoption;
                            });
                            }
                            });
                            });
</script>
```

but my array looks like this:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [manu] => hp [typ] => typ1 ) [1] => Array ( [manu] => HP [typ] => typ2 ) [2] => Array ( [manu] => HP [typ] => typ3)

and I can only access the array is 0 or 1 or 3. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
var options = $("#artikel-select");
$.each(json, function() {
    options.append($("<option />").val(this.type).text(this.manu));
});
```